# Changing Navbar links after logging out in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, navbar

I am developing my project with reactjs and redux and so I want to show different Links in Navbar when I'm logged in or logged out. When I click on Login it's ok and everything work correctly but when I click on Logout it doesn't change Navbar automaticclly and I have to refresh the page. Can any body help me?
Here is my Navbar.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { selectAccessToken } from '../features/authentications/authenticationsSlice';

import axios from 'axios';

import './Navbar.css';

export const Navbar = (props) => {
   const [loggedIn , setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
   
   let accessToken = useSelector(selectAccessToken);
   const [token, setToken] = useState(accessToken)
   const dispatch = useDispatch()

   const [loggedOut, setLoggedOut] = useState([]);

   const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

   const LOGOUT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts_api/v1/dj-rest-auth/logout/';

   const history = useHistory()
  
   const removeTokens  = async () => {

      try {
         const response = await axios.post(`${LOGOUT_URL}`, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}` }})
         const data = response.data;
         setLoggedOut(data)      

         console.log("data: ", data)
      }
      catch (err) {
         console.log('err', err)
         setErrors(err)
      }

    }




  const handleLogout = async () => {
   await logout();
   history.push("login/");
 };


  const logout = () => {
   
      removeTokens()
      localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
      localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token")
      console.log('localstrorage token after logout: ', localStorage.getItem("access_token"))
      setLoggedIn(false);
      accessToken = null

      console.log('accesstoken after logout:', accessToken)
 }




   if (accessToken) {
      return (
         <nav>
            <ul className="menu">
   
            <li className="logo"> My logo </li>
            
            <li className="item">
            <Link to="/">
               articles
            </Link>
         
            </li>
            <li>
               <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
            </li>
         
   
            <li>
               <Link to="/articles">Seconds</Link>
            </li>
            

            <li className="item">
               <Link to="/management">
                  management
               </Link>
             </li>

            <li className="item">
               <Link to="/" onClick={handleLogout}>
                  Logout
               </Link>
            </li>
   
            </ul>
   
         </nav>
     )
   } else if (!accessToken) {

      return (
         <nav>
            <ul className="menu">
   
            <li className="logo"> My logo </li>
            
            <li className="item">
            <Link to="/">
               articles
            </Link>
         
            </li>
            <li>
               <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
            </li>
         
   
            <li>
               <Link to="/articles">Seconds</Link>
            </li>
            

            <li className="item">
         <Link 
            to="/login" 
            onClick={() => {
                 localStorage.setItem("access_token", true);
                 setLoggedIn(true);
               }
             }
            >
            Login
         </Link>
      </li>
   
            </ul>
   
         </nav>
     )
   }
   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set accessToken to be null like this inside your logout.
This accessToken is a reference of your access token in your redux state. Your redux state still contains the access token.

```
accessToken = null
```

You have to create the `action` the put accessToken as null from the redux.
And then call the function on logout.

Comment: I know but the problem is not that. because after changing accessToken it doesnt change Navbar as I want

Comment: Did you create an action and update your state to redux and set it to `null`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. For the first I didnt underestand what you said now it is solved!